# What is "User stylesheet" in Google Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

I know about `user agent stylesheet` but I am seeing `user stylesheet` only on some specific sites in the Styles section of the developer tools, even though there is no `Custom.css` in my `User Stylesheets` in my Chrome Profile.

Comment: Browsers are supposed to support user style sheets (CSS 2.2, 3.2 UA Conformance, "UAs must allow users to specify a file that contains the user style sheet. UAs that run on devices without any means of writing or specifying files are exempted from this requirement.", https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/conform.html#conformance) – However, Google Chrome intentionally broke this. The extension API still exists that allows creating user style sheet via extensions which is computationally the same thing but harder to use. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347016 for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These "User stylesheet"s are added by Chrome extensions, either [declared in a manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration), or using [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS).

Styles on the web page always take precedence over the user stylesheet, unless the rule set in the (extension's) user stylesheet has a higher [specifity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

If you want to know which extension is responsible for these stylesheets, just disable the extensions one by one until the stylesheet goes away. After disabling an extension, select a different element in the inspector, then select the original element to refresh the view, you don't have to reload the page.

Comment: Is there any simpler method to identify the extension causing this?

Comment: @eldos Search in the Extensions directory of your [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) for the offending extension. In most cases, the style sheet is declared in a file called `manifest.json` (e.g. `"content_scripts": [{ "css": ["style.css"], ...`).