# What purpose does <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> serves?

Tags: html

During an system update, I saw the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<script>
    //Redirect Logic....
    location.href = "https://www.example.com";
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p>
        Click <a href="https://www.example.com">here</a> to access the service you requested.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The above page is to redirect user from one page to another, do note that it is a  legacy code.

And the part about **< body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >** curious me, the previous developer of this page clearly want to specified that the background should be white.

Which is strange because from my experience, all browser by default is white, **< body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >** doesn't seems to serves any purpose.

My question is, can anybody be able to guess why this **< body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >** code is in there? Maybe some browser used to be black? It would be nice to find out before I inevitably remove this html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all browser **by default** is white

Indeed. By default. It will override a [user CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465939/what-is-user-stylesheet-in-google-chromes-developer-tools), unless the user CSS specifies the `background` to be `!important`.

Also, see some historical images - I believe [Mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser)#/media/File:NCSA_Mosaic.PNG) used to have grey background by default.

Comment: @Andifined: Yes. The question is "why is this here", not "how to write it better".

Comment: Absolutely, I also gave you an upvote. Just wanted to add that bit of information :)

Comment: `I believe Mosaic used to have grey background by default` Didn't know that some browser used to be non white! You question give the best explanation to my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I usually make no assumptions on browser's defaults and always define everything the way it is intended to be. There are a few reasons:

- Code should not be short. It should be readable. Relying on browser defaults makes it less readable, hence worse.
- Defaults can change. Apple might change Safari's default background tomorrow to a nice light grey and you won't even get notified about it.

I think you are not considering the additional mental effort that is required from anyone who will read that code in the future. It is not trivial at all and is a big waste of resources, bigger than the cost of having a few bytes more of code.

Moreover, I find it almost impossible to list all browsers that exist. If you think differently, look at any list of user agents and you'll be surprised.
[Here is the first one Google presented me](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php/). I *will not* waste time researching what the defaults of each of them are.

EDIT: other answers point out that the `bgcolor` attribute is deprecated or criticize inline styles. While all those considerations are valid, I wanted to answer about whether to specify a background or not, regardless of the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Bgcolor is one of those attributes that has become deprecated with the implementation of Cascading Style Sheets so it doesnt really do much :D

Answer (score 1):

It serves no purpose, since as you stated the browser standard ist #ffffff.
Also, in HTML5, the bgcolor attribute is deprecated and should be replaced with css.

Comment: I understand that, which is what I will do if I need to keep the background color to white.

Answer (score 1):

Some extensions for browsers may change your website's background color. Maybe in this way the previous developer tried to avoid this thing.
Also, using inline styles you can't rewrite background-color property of the body. (Only if you want to use !important)

Answer (score 1):

Earlier it was used to change the background of whole element. But it is depreciated now. Now we use **background-color** css property instead of this. You can remove this since its the default background color.